# Does reverting edits by Poster that adds an answer into their question deviate from the original intent of that post?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Clearly, I do not think editing a question, which has suitable answers, to include an answer that is not among those answers (and calling it a solution) in any way reflects the original intent of the question.  I'm struggling to understand how anyone could think that way.  It's Q&A not QA&A.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21859635

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should have been approved, yes. The reviewers probably saw that you've removed code from the question, but weren't paying too much attention to the context of the edit.

I've retroactively approved the review, so you'll receive credit for the edit, along with the reputation.